# Rutas de laravel con Ubuntu no sirven - Digital Ocean

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, digitalocean

He subido un proyecto a digital ocean.

Exactamente : Ubuntu LAMP on 18.04

Ya me muestra mi proyecto pero solamente el Home.

Pero cuando quiero ir a otras rutas, no me muestra nada, me sale err
que la Vista no se encontró.

He entrado ahí

```html
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Lo tengo así, Tal y como lo he  visto en otras paginas.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/atenea/public

        <Directory /var/www/atenea/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /var/www/atenea/public
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Igual he entrado aquí

```
sudo nano  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

ahí lo tengo así

```html
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

he puesto los comandos

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

mi . htaccess

lo tengo en el root del proyecto supongo que ahí debe de ir no¿?.
bueno ahí tengo esto.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

No sé que esta mal. me sigue saliendo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**" EN LOCAL TODO FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE "**

PERO, EN LOCAL ESTOY USANDO NGINX - CON LARAVEL VALET (MAC)

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas Nginx en DigitalOcean? eso ayudaría a elimiar o reducir problemas de este tipo.

Comment: @Shaz la verdad es que eso hice mejor, pero .. según todo tenfog configurado pero me sale un erro ahora no puedo entrar al home.. me dice Please log into your Droplet with SSH to configure the LEMP installation.

Answer (score 0):

La ruta si funciona, el error es por la vista que no encuentra.
Necesitaría detalles de tus archivos, por que no comprates tu repositorio y así te puedo ayudar.